# How to get get current page row no into checkbox of one of the columns of displaytag in struts1?

Tags: pagination

I am using struts1..
 my code is something like below..
When I try to delete any row from next pages.. the index starts from 1st once again.. how to get the actual row number???

```
<html:form action="deleteCust" method="post" styleId="custForm" onsubmit="delete_customer()">

<input type="button" onclick="document.location='addCustomer.jsp'" value="Add Customer" />
    <html:submit>Delete</html:submit    
       <div id="result" class="navbar">
     <form action="#" method="post">
<% java.util.ArrayList< beanPackage.CustomerBean> al=new java.util.ArrayList< beanPackage.CustomerBean>(); 
 daoPackage.DAOClass dao=new daoPackage.DAOClass();
 al = dao.viewCustomerDetails();
  %> <% request.setAttribute("CustomerTable",al); int i=0;
// String currentPageNo=request.getParameter("page");

// int i=Integer.parseInt(currentPageNo);*/
// System.out.println((Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter((new ParamEncoder(tab).encodeParameterName(TableTagParameters.PARAMETER_PAGE))))));
%>


<display:table
name="CustomerTable" pagesize="6" export="true" requestURI="#" class="displayTable" >
<display:column title="Select" media="html">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" class="menuFont" value="<%=al.get(i++).getCustomerId()%>">  </display:column>
<display:column property="customerId" title="ID" paramId="customerId" href="modify_Customer.jsp?${row.id}" />
<display:column property="customerName" class="menuFont" title="Name" />
<display:column property="city" class="menuFont" title="City" />
<display:column property="state" class="menuFont" title="State" />
<display:column property="country" class="menuFont" title="Country" />
<display:column property="primaryContact" class="menuFont" title="Primary Contact" />
<display:column property="secondaryContact" class="menuFont" title="Secondary Contact" />
<display:column property="emailId" autolink="true" class="menuFont" title="EmailId" />
<display:column property="altEmailId" autolink="true" class="menuFont" title="Alternate EmailId" media="excel" />

<display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement">bottom</display:setProperty>
```

Comment: Solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188819/displaytag-struts-2-go-to-specific-page/16195257#16195257

Answer (score 1):

I had same error(1 year later), i find a solution passing the displaytag parameters on form jsp...
somthing like this:

```
<html:hidden property="d-16544-s" value='<%=request.getParameter("d-16544-s")%>'/>
<html:hidden property="d-16544-p" value='<%=request.getParameter("d-16544-p")%>'/>
<html:hidden property="d-16544-o" value='<%=request.getParameter("d-16544-o")%>'/>
```