# Displaytag struts 2 go to specific page

Tags: jsp, struts2, pagination, displaytag, ognl

in my project i'm using display tag. The problem comes when the results returned are like e.g. 300 pages. The user needs to jump to page e.g. 200 but he can't. He needs to go slowly there ( 5 pages at a time or so ). I want to add the ability to the user to choose in a drop-down the page he wants to jump to. Is there any property in display-tag or any suggestion?

Comment: http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/configuration.html - paging.banner.full - I think, {0}: numbered pages list, is what you are looking for

Comment: @Sumit No this is not what I'm looking for. This is for the default (8) pages. I want to add a drop-down that includes all pages.

Comment: Have you tried ? Do you still have problems ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**ParamEncoder**](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/apidocs/org/displaytag/util/ParamEncoder.html) to get the **name** (and eventually the **value**) of `displayTag`'s parameters, specified in [**TableTagParameters.html**](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/displaytag/apidocs/org/displaytag/tags/TableTagParameters.html), in your case `PARAMETER_PAGE`.

```
<div>
    With Scriptlets 
    <br/>
    <% String pageNumParameter = 
              new org.displaytag.util.ParamEncoder("id_of_your_displaytag_table").encodeParameterName(org.displaytag.tags.TableTagParameters.PARAMETER_PAGE); %>
    [parameter name] = <%= pageNumParameter %>
    <br/>
    [parameter value]= <%= request.getParameter(pageNumParameter) %> 
</div>

<div>
    With OGNL
    <br/>   
    <s:set var="pageNumParameter" 
           value="%{new org.displaytag.util.ParamEncoder('id_of_your_displaytag_table').encodeParameterName(@org.displaytag.tags.TableTagParameters@PARAMETER_PAGE)}" />        
    [parameter name] = <s:property value="%{#pageNumParameter}"/>
    <br/>
    [parameter value]= <s:property value="#parameters[#pageNumParameter]"/>
</div>
```

Then you should be able to craft a `request` by passing the *dynamic* generated parameter for that table, with the value you want (from a `SelectBox`, from an `Input Text`, from a script etc)